# Php, isset - default value, can it be simplified?

Tags: php, mysql

here is something:

```
$result = $this->getSomething();

$db = new Db();
$db->save($result['DATA']); // might exists or not
$db->save($result['IP']); // might exists or not
$db->save($result['X']); // might exists or not
```

but those array keys are not sure to be exists. Of corse I can always write this:

```
$result = $this->getSomething();

if (!isset($result['DATA']))
{
    $result['DATA'] = null;
}
//same for the other keys

$db = new Db();
$db->save($result['DATA']);
$db->save($result['IP']);
$db->save($result['X']);
```

but its very cumbersome job. Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: you could declare them beforehand, so they get overwritten with the desired results, or stay default if that fails.

Comment: @Burki no he can't because the whole `$result` variable gets the value returned by `$this->getSomething()`

Answer (score 5):

Starting at PHP 7 (which every should start using anyway), you can use the new coalesce operator to do this:

```
$db->save($result['DATA'] ?? null);
```

Comment: Definitely +1 for this case, though this can get rather repetitive if you need to do this multiple times within the same script for the same key...

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = $this->getSomething();
$result += array_fill_keys(['DATA', 'IP', 'X'], null);
```

This populates any of these keys which don't exist with `null`.
Can even be written as `$result = $this->getSomething() + array_fill_keys(..);`.

- [`+` array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)
- [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys)

Comment: this is bad design if you think about maintaining your code. you always have to think about putting new associative array-keys into your list. you should see what you do with the code at the point where it's needed; so at each of these lines e.g.: `$db->save($result['X']);` it should be visible that the value is set to `null` if the variable is not available.

Comment: You have a point there, but what if you want to access the same key several times within the same script? It gets rather repetitive having to expect the value being non existing each time. It's the same as initialising all variables you expect to use at the top of a scope.

Comment: yes, if you want to reuse them, it's a pain in the...  I always hated stuff like this in PHP and I am looking forward to PHP 7's option with the coalesce operator like Berry Langerak posted in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$data = !isset($result['DATA']) ? null : $result['Data'];
$ip = !isset($result['IP']) ? null : $result['IP'];
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you would be use OOP way

your method getSomething() must return instance of some class (ex. SomeData) instead of array

```
/**
 * @return SomeData
 */
public function getSomething()
{
    /*
     * some code
     */

    return new SomeData($data, $x, $ip);
}
```

SomeData class

```
class SomeData
{
private $data;
private $ip;
private $x;

public function __construct($data, $ip, $x)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->ip = $ip;
    $this->x = $x;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $data
 */
public function setData($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIp()
{
    return $this->ip;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $ip
 */
public function setIp($ip)
{
    $this->ip = $ip;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getX()
{
    return $this->x;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $x
 */
public function setX($x)
{
    $this->x = $x;
}

}
```

And finaly you work with result without worrying about isset and etc.

```
$result = $this->getSomething();

$db = new Db();
$db->save($result->getData());
$db->save($result->getIp());
$db->save($result->getX());
```